Numpy dependency errors while installing the RPM Package
I've created a RPM Package for a python application using setuptools and rpmbuild,
the application need few modules like numpy,flask..etc,I've install all the modules in the package itself.
but while installing the rpm I'm getting these errors
error: Failed dependencies:
        libgfortran-2e0d59d6.so.5.0.0(GFORTRAN_8)(64bit) is needed by test_app-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
        libquadmath-2d0c479f.so.0.0.0(QUADMATH_1.0)(64bit) is needed by test_app-1.0-1.el7.x86_64

When I uninstall numpy from the package and install in my local then the rpm package is working as expected. Don't know why it's behaving like this,
